# Set_select() not working on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a  select box in my form and when I hit submit the form goes through validation and if an error happens, return all the value. This work expect for my select box, I have use the set_select  but it doesnt work data comes in data base

```
<select name="leave_category_id" class="form-control" onchange="check_leave_category(this.value)" required  >
    <option value="" >Select Leave Category...</option>
    <?php foreach ($all_leave_category as $v_category) :

        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $v_category->leave_category_id ?>" >
            <?php echo set_select('leave_category_id',$cat); ?>
            <?php echo $v_category->category ?>  </option>
    <?php endforeach;

    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: show your  form and controller code?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post also your actual code, so someone can look at it and give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`set_select()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_select#set_select) function prints out the `selected="selected"` attribute in the `<option>` element where appropriate. But your code is as follows:

```
<option value="<?php echo $v_category->leave_category_id ?>" >
                                                             ^
                                    closing the tag   -->    |
    <?php echo set_select('leave_category_id',$cat); ?>
    <?php echo $v_category->category ?>  
</option>
```

So when you look at the html, it will look something like this:

```
<option value="123">selected="selected" Category Name</option>
```

Got it? Your `selected` attribute is placed outside the tag. I guess you'll be able to fix it now ;)

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $v_category->leave_category_id ?>" 
                                                  <?php echo set_value('leave_category_id',$cat);?>> <?php echo $v_category->category ?>  </option>

Comment: Right. You're not being very helpful... if you want us to help, at least tell us what your code produces and what is the expected output. And please edit your question instead of dumping some code in a comment as it's a lot harder to read.

Comment: i want the select box value remain same as i post the first time after the redirection

Comment: And the value is correctly inserted AND selected from the database? Have you tried to `var_dump($cat)`? and compared it to `var_dump($v_category->leave_category_id)`?