# set_select() not working in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want the select box show the same value before the from submit after the redirection in this code $cat value come to the session  i am not using validation rule for select box i want only the select box not change after the redirection 
    
        Select Leave Category...
        
            leave_category_id ?>"

```
                <?php echo set_select('leave_category_id', $cat, true); ?>> <?php echo $v_category->category ?>  </option>

    <?php endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code too??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set\_select() not working on CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447909/set-select-not-working-on-codeigniter)

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: the answer you are giving me it's not working giorgio please help me

Comment: unable to understand your words **I want the select box show the same value before the from submit after the redirection**.You can use hindi if you feel difficulty in english

Comment: See if this [link](http://i.nt.ro/using-form_dropdown-in-codeigniter-to-populate-from-the-database/) can help

Comment: i want the select box value should not be change after the from redirection .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<select name="leave_category_id" class="form-control" onchange="check_leave_category(this.value)" required  >
    <option>Select Leave Category...</option>
    <?php foreach ($all_leave_category as $v_category) :

        // Using short tag
        //$v_category->leave_category_id == $cat ? $selected = 'selected' : $selected = '';

        // without using short tag
        if($v_category->leave_category_id == $cat) $selected = 'selected'; else $selected = '';
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $v_category->leave_category_id ?>" <?php echo $selected?> > <?php echo $v_category->category ?>  </option>

    <?php endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: it is showing last value of for each loop only after  the redirection every tmie

Comment: @gopal why you need `onchange="check_leave_category(this.value)"`?

Comment: i am using on-change event to fire ajax call on the base upon  select box value for different task

Comment: @gopal option would be automatically selected when user select option. Then why you need the above code.

Comment: i want the select box value should not be change after the from redirection .

Comment: Please let me know what is the url after redirection.

Comment: it's come to the same view page after redirection

Comment: @gopal please accept/vote up my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: sorry @Hassan sir my reputation less then 15

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to keep in mind: First you have to use the validation class to be able to use the `set_select()` function. Second you have to pass the database information to that function, like this:

```
<select name="myselect">
  <option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', ($model->selection == 'one')); ?> >One</option>
  <option value="two" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'two', ($model->selection == 'two')); ?> >Two</option>
  <option value="three" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'three', ($model->selection == 'three')); ?> >Three</option>
</select>
```

If `$model->selection` is `two`, then the second option will be selected in the example above.

see the [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select)